# Using Trace view in Android

Tags: android

i would like to know when and where we can use the **Trace View** effectively.

i really confused where to use this in application.

Thanks in adv...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi put this code in your application

```
  // start tracing to "/sdcard/calc.trace"
Debug.startMethodTracing("Name of yours");
// ...
// stop tracing
Debug.stopMethodTracing();
```

it will store the trace details in the SDCArd

for more details see the below link

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html